# Basic SQL Select in Postgresql fails

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am doing a select * on a postgresql table, and everything looks good. But if I do:

```
SELECT Name from People
```

It says:

```
ERROR: column People.Name does not exist
SQL state: 42703
Character: 8
```

But the name column shows up during select *. I've tried:

```
SELECT People.Name from People
```

as well, with the same result. Am I missing something? It should be pretty easy to do this in any other database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting quotation marks around the column name, i.e. "Name"

Comment: Workes, but I can't see why I can't just use the regular name without quotes.

Comment: probably because Name is a reserve word.

Comment: And also for the reason explained by George (lowercasing).

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL converts everything to lowercase.

If you asks for this:

```
CREATE TABLE People
{
id SERIAL,
Att1 varchar(100)
-- constraints
};

SELECT Name FROM People;
```

You should get all the information, because pgsql converts this to

```
CREATE TABLE people
{
id SERIAL,
att1 varchar(100),
-- constraints
};

SELECT name FROM people;
```

If you built your table with pgAdmin and created field with mixed casing, you will need to quote them to be sucessfull, like this:

```
SELECT "Att1" FROM people
```

Answer (score 1):

`Name` is a keyword, so it might not be handled well in this case.  The best thing to do would be to alias the table like this:

`SELECT Name from People`**`p`**

and then use the `p` to select the column:

`SELECT`**`p.Name`**`from People p`

Comment: Sorry I used Name as an example, my real field is not a keyname. I suspect it's a casing issue, but I used the same case shown in the GUI.